# How to create a build type folder in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So i'm following this book with android studio to learn how to develop basic android application but i have a problem with the build types.
The book tells me to create a different build type and makes me edit the build.gradle file of my just-now-created project (i don't even know if this is correct in English, but..) so that it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPSCO.jpg
than it tells me that i have to create the "perf" folder with a java and a res folder with inside all the default files i need ( java file and values) but i don't know how to do it...
Please i can't get my head around of this, i read like 424320 other discussions here...
how directories should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQZch.jpg

build.gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 signingConfigs {
     config {
     }
 }
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.example.mario.apobus"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 25
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner        
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '  
'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
    perf.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
     perf {
        applicationIdSuffix ".pref"
        versionNameSuffix "-perf"
        buildConfigField "String", "PERF_URL",   
 "\"https://myperfserver/data\""
    }
}
}

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',       
 {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  }
```

Comment: do you mean build type or build flavor? You shouldn't need to restructure your project at all to add a build type. Post your `app/build.gradle` file

Comment: It's a build Type, the book wants me to create a Performance.java file but doesn't tell me how to do it

Comment: You keep saying build type but the structure in the picture is consistent with adding a build flavor.

Comment: the books says i'm creating a build type...
I guess i'll just go on with the book hoping it will get clear soon

Comment: ok best of luck to you